# Where can I find a high-res version of the favicon for an SE site?

Tags: support, chat, favicon

I'm setting up a custom feed reader for our main room on RPG and I'd like to use the favicon as the icon for the feed reader.  I tried using `favicon.ico` as the icon, but that looks very blurry.  Since I've seen other sites do it, I assume there's a higher res version around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be a better place, but I found this in the source and it seems to work fine.

`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://sstatic.net/rpg/img/apple-touch-icon.png">`

Comment: yes, just use the `apple-touch-icon.png`

Answer (score 0):

Stackauth "sites" gives logo, Davison and touch paths.

Well, vNext gives favicon... But definitely gives the touch path.