# How can I configure the feed reader in my chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat, feed

How can I setup the feed reader in my chatroom to have a name, picture, and description?

Comment: I don't think this can be done...

Comment: @George I'm happy to let you know you are wrong!

Comment: Note: several of the operations involved here are moderator only.

Comment: @Marc That's why there's a rub...

Answer (score 7):

First click on the `room`, and then `Manage Feeds`

[image: Rooms and feeds]

Next fill in your favorite feed, and click `add this feed`.

[image: Feed creation]

**If you're a moderator you can do the following things to customize the feed reader.**

---

Then click the `create user` button to make a custom feed reader.

[image: Create user]

Now click the *boring* name of the feed.

[image: User Link]

1. Replace the name
2. Replace the picture.  The [apple touch icon for your site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67137/where-can-i-find-a-high-res-version-of-the-favicon-for-an-se-site/67140#67140) is a good place to start.
3. Give it an *exciting* description.
4. Click `save changes`
   [image: Edit user]

That's it, you have your own custom feed reader!

Comment: Bleah, why is it only mods can create custom users for Feeds?

Comment: @R.Bemrose I don't know.  I'm not thrilled with that myself.